# One specific Webresource.axd empty in IIS7.5 with app pool in integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, httpmodule

Folks,

I have a page in my site that has a request to webresource.axd that returns 0 bytes. All other calls to webresource.axd work. Decrypting the d querystring parameter I get s|WebForms.js. This results in the error "ReferenceError: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions is not defined", which makes me a sad panda.

The weird thing is that the page works when the app pool is set to "Classic" mode -- it fails under integrated mode. Alas, putting the site in classic mode causes another set of problems.

Any thoughts on where to look?

Edit:

- compression is not turned on
- the httphandler is set up, and "verify file exists" isn't on.

Edit #2: Changes from IIS 7 to IIS 7.5 (duh)